# Prefixed route path gives error in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

After upgrading to Rails 4 a route with a prefixed name and slash is throwing an error.

```
actionpack-4.0.1.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:239:in `default_controller_and_action': 
    'MyEngine/dashboard' 
    is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems.
```

In routes.rb I have

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/foo", :as => 'my_engine'

  match 'dashboard' => 'MyEngine/dashboard', via: :get
```

And in the mounted engine MyEngine:

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
    match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', via: :get
```

This works well in Rails 3.2, but in Rails 4 the slash in 'MyEngine/dashboard' throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

Using an engine, you can directly create routes to the engine's controllers and actions in your routes file like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/foo", :as => 'my_engine'

  get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'
end
```

Comment: The action is in a mounted engine called MyEngine, which has match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', via: :get

Comment: Thanks but the engine is already mounted, I've added extra details to the original question.

Comment: That route is to a controller in the host app, I'm trying to set a route to the mounted app's dashboard controller, but at /dashboard rather than /foo/fashboard

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to set a route in the host application to a controller in a mounted engine (mounted on "/foo") at the top level, e.g. /foo/dashboard calls the mounted engine's 'dashboard#index' action, and I want /dashboard to do the same.

I'm adding a controller of the same name in the host application and doing a redirect to the mounted engine controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, change this line

```
match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', via: :get
```

as

```
get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'
```